# Why is my piezo buzzer emitting a clicking sound?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, 555, piezo-buzzer

I'm trying to make a voltage controlled oscillator (VCO.) It works just fine, but my piezo buzzer keeps clicking in conjunction with the square wave the NE555P is producing, making a weird effect. Is there a way to remove it?

[image: Circuit made with tinkercad]

I'm sorry if the circuit is not readable, I do have a PCB schematic here as well. I have made a (messy) circuit diagram.

[image]   [image]

Comment: I realized that the pcb has only 1 potentiometer and the Tinkercad layout has 2. My mistake

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. There's no need to comment on your own question. You can use the [edit] link to add additional information.

Comment: Any decent PCB CAD tool will have an integrated schematics editor. Drawing layouts that aren't connected to a schematic is a very bad idea.

Comment: Ground is missing in your schematic. Lack of decoupling on Vcc. What’s feeding it? Is Vcc stable under load?

Comment: Winny Im sorry I dont really understand. Im missing ground? If so how do I fix it?

Comment: In your schematic, pin 1 of the 55 is tied to Vcc. This is not correct and does not correspond to your layout. Please place a capacitor between pin 1 and pin 8 of your 555. Probe it and see if it's stable. Where do you source 3.1 V from?

Comment: The 3.1 would come from a power supply. And I might just be able to use a square to sine filter

Comment: So I added a filter and that sorted out most of the issues, I will proceed to close this question, I cannot close this question . . .

Comment: Note in the PCB layout, the 555 pin 3 goes up and underneath R1, where it changes sides (via) right at R1's +V input.  This will not work, as it means the 555 pin 3 is connected to +V.

Comment: Ah good to know, I should have caught that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You show a 3.1 V power supply but the datasheet for a [NE555P](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ne555) specifies operation over a 5-15 V supply range so you need to use a supply voltage in that range.

> my piezo buzzer keeps clicking in conjunction with the square wave the NE555P is producing

That's what they do. A Google search for your buzzer part number shows that it doesn't have an internal oscillator so you'll get a click whenever the voltage across it changes. To get an audible tone you'll need to set up the 555 to generate an audio frequency. The buzzer is specified to be self-resonant at 4000 ± 500 Hz so will be loudest around those frequencies. Unfortunately the lack of detail in your diagrams means that we can't tell what frequency your circuit works at.

Are you just simulating this or have you built a physical circuit? Do you have a scope or a DMM with frequency measurement to let you see what frequency you are sending to the buzzer?

Comment: I am currently just simulating this, I could use tinkercad's scope function to track the frequency

Comment: @Dcybroz - So the piezo in your simulation is clicking?